# Is the retard potential of the electricmagnetic force consistent with the Lienard-Wiechert potential?

Tags: special-relativity, electrostatics, field-theory

The equation (62.9) of L.D. Landau's book >, we derive the retard potential
$$\phi=\int\frac{\rho_{t-R/c}}{R}dV+\phi_0$$
$$\mathrm{A}=\int\frac{\mathrm{j}_{t-R/c}}{R}dV+\phi_0$$
But in the next chapter, we derive the Lienard-Wiechert potential for a single particle
$$\phi=\frac{q}{R-\mathrm{v}\cdot\mathrm{R}/c}$$
$$\mathrm{A}=\frac{q}{R-\mathrm{v}\cdot\mathrm{R}/c}\frac{\mathrm{v}}{c}$$
As we can see, we can't derive the retard potential from the Lienard-Wiechert potential, even though we regard the potential of a continuous current as a combination of each individual charged particle. The reason for the conflict may come from the extra aberration factor.
$$1-\frac{\mathrm{v}\cdot\mathrm{R}}{Rc}$$
I also try to derive the Lienard-Wiechart potential from the retard potential by using
$$j^\mu(x^\mu)=qc\beta^\mu\delta(\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}_0(t)$$
So we have
$$A^\mu(x^\mu)=\frac{1}{c}\int d^3\mathrm{r^\prime}\int dt^\prime\frac{qc\beta^\mu(t^\prime)\delta(\mathrm{r}^\prime(t^\prime)-\mathrm{r}_0(t^\prime))}{|\mathrm{r}(t)-\mathrm{r}^\prime(t^\prime)|}\delta\left(t^\prime-t+\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)$$
$$=q\int d^3\mathrm{r^\prime}\int d t^\prime\frac{\beta^\mu(t^\prime)\delta(\mathrm{r}^\prime(t^\prime)-\mathrm{r}_0(t^\prime))}{|\mathrm{r}(t)-\mathrm{r}^\prime(t^\prime)|}\delta\left(t^\prime-t+\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)$$
$$=q\int d^3\mathrm{r^\prime}\frac{\beta^\mu\left(t-\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)\delta\left(\mathrm{r}^\prime\left(t-\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)-\mathrm{r}_0\left(t-\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)\right)}{|\mathrm{r}(t)-\mathrm{r}^\prime\left(t-\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)|}$$
$$=q\frac{\beta^\mu\left(t-\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime|}{c}\right)}{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}^\prime\left(t-\frac{|\mathrm{r}-\mathrm{r}_0|}{c}\right)|}$$
I still fail to derive the aberration factor. How to solve it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#:~:text=The%20Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert%20potentials%20describe,potential%20in%20the%20Lorenz%20gauge. Under derivation

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. It does solve my doubt.